# Closing the flag popup also closes the close popup

Tags: bug, flags

This is an extremely rare scenario:

When i was about to vote to close a question, by chance i clicked `flag` option, realized it and quickly clicked the close option. Two popups opened one after the another:

[image]

But clicking the close button in flag popup also closed the close popup.

this is a silly thing to report, but i'm posting because the fix should be silly as well, just for the sake of reporting.

*Side note:* Giving different dimensions for both the popups and aligning them nicely seems to be a clever idea in this case, but useless when the close popup is over the other one. If the smaller one always has a higher `z-index`, user can always (*Well actually, when he - rarely - clicks both options together*) choose which popup to choose...